# How I can use a UIImagePickerController to add an image to a tweet?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, twitter, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to iOS development so I'm confused. I have a ViewController, in this ViewController there are many UIButtons. How I can open the picker and add the image to the tweet using `addImage`?
PS: I'm using Storyboard.

Thanks and sorry for my english... :)

Comment: Dude.. Go through some docs and googling before posting these type of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when the button is pressed, you want to do something like:

```
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];        

    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;  

    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
  }
```

you need to implement the delegate methods. the main one is:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    // do twitter stuff here....

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

for more information, see the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PickinganItemfromthePhotoLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010408-SW1