# How can I get this to appear when action is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get this to appear from an action within an app? I have tried searching google but not find anything about it and not sure what is would even be called. Any advice or links to tutorials would be great.

[image]

Comment: learn [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: It's called UIImagePickerController. Please look at this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991613/how-i-can-use-a-uiimagepickercontroller-to-add-an-image-to-a-tweet

Comment: @AlexanderTkachenko this is a good point. `BenThompson` are you talking about the `UIActionSheet` itself which that is or are you talking about what those buttons are actually doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a UIActionSheet. See [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801). Or this [tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/ios-7-views-uiactionsheet).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`UIActionSheet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{ 
     // Create an instance of your UIActionSheet setting the buttons and the delegate to self.
     UIActionSheet *actSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                            desctructionButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [actSheet showInView];
}
```

Remember to include the `UIActionSheetDelegate` in you `interface` file like

```
@interface MySubClass : MySuperClass <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

**Side Note**

Whilst that image that you have provided is a `UIActionSheet` the buttons that it is showing are part of the [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) Class, if it is these buttons you are after take a look at the `UIImagePickerController` class.